# When the dataframe has duplicate columns, it seems that fillna function cannot work correctly with dict parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I find that after using pd.concat() to concatenate two dataframes with same column name, then df.fillna() will not work correctly with the dict parameter specifying which value to use for each column.

I don't know why? Is something wrong with my understanding?

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
a2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [np.nan, 20, 30]})
c = pd.DataFrame({'c': [40, np.nan, 60]})
x = pd.concat([a1,a2, b, c], axis=1)
print(x)
x = x.fillna({'b':10, 'c': 50})
print(x)
```

Initial dataframe:

```
   a  a     b     c
0  1  1   NaN  40.0
1  2  2  20.0   NaN
2  3  3  30.0  60.0
```

Data is unchanged after df.fillna():

```
   a  a     b     c
0  1  1   NaN  40.0
1  2  2  20.0   NaN
2  3  3  30.0  60.0
```

Comment: I think the issue is related to the fact that you have duplicate columns. If you get rid of one them, it works as expected.

Comment: @BallpointBen, yep, if I remove the dulicate columns, it works correctly. So I wonder what happens when duplicate columns appear?

Comment: Another interesting observation: `x.iloc[0,0]=2` changes the first row in both 'a' columns.

Comment: I get the feeling this issue is related to [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12344) somehow...

Comment: And here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13423

Comment: Please check https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/7265d29d3a8bf5d1750b8991c5588b4f3d7fd5ce

Comment: Submit this issue to the pandas repo please.

Comment: I guess this is technically a bug, but it is NEVER a good idea to have duplicate column names and pandas shouldn't even allow it IMO, but since it does, I guess it should work in cases like this.  Nevertheless, great example of why you shouldn't have duplicate column names.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there's a problem assigning values to a dataframe in the presence of duplicate column names.
However, you can use this workaround:

```
for col,val in {'b':10, 'c': 50}.items():
    new_col = x[col].fillna(val)
    idx = int(x.columns.get_loc(col))
    x = x.drop(col,axis=1)
    x.insert(loc=idx, column=col, value=new_col)

print(x)
```

result:

```
   a  a     b     c
0  1  1  10.0  40.0
1  2  2  20.0  50.0
2  3  3  30.0  60.0
```